# sshexec ant task. How to not show the output

Tags: ant, ssh, task

I have a task sshexec in an ant buildfile. This task shows the output of the command i wish to execute. My question is: how to not show the output?

here is my task:

```
<sshexec verbose="false" failonerror="true"
  trust="yes" host="${app.deploy.server}"
  username="${deploy.user}"
  command="find /home/software/public_html/${app.name} -name *.jar* -exec md5sum {} +"
  password="${deploy.password}"
  output="jarsAtServer.txt" outputproperty="trash" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my task: <sshexec verbose="false" failonerror="true" trust="yes" host="${app.deploy.server}" username="${deploy.user}" command="find /home/software/public_html/${app.name} -name *.jar* -exec md5sum {} +" password="${deploy.password}" output="jarsAtServer.txt" outputproperty="trash" />

Comment: I fixed the formatting so that your task is visible in the question.  You may want to look at the first section [markdown documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)...

Comment: Have you tried running Ant in quiet mode using the `-q` flag? http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options

Comment: I want to have some output. i Just want to omit the sshexec output. I have the attributte output="jarsAtServer.txt" so i guess the output should only be in this file... Not printing to the screen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can silence the output from sshexec task (or any other task) by using a custom logger:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.*;
public class MuteTaskLogger extends DefaultLogger
{
    public void messageLogged(BuildEvent event)
    {
        Task task = event.getTask();
        if (task != null &&
            task.getTaskName().equals(event.getProject().getProperty("mute.task")))
        {
            return;
        }
        super.messageLogged(event);
    }
}
```

Compile with:

```
javac -cp ant.jar MuteTaskLogger.java
```

The task to mute is specified with the property "mute.task":

```
ant -logger MuteTaskLogger -Dmute.task=sshexec -lib <folder-of-MuteTaskLogger-class>
```

You can tidy it up by putting MuteTaskLogger into one of the [Ant library directories](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#libs). The logger and mute.task properties can be added to the [ANT_ARGS environment variable](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#envvars).

Answer (score 2):

The ant sshexec outputs the command it will execute as well as the output of the command. The suppresssystemout (since ant 1.9.0) flag can be used to suppress the output of the command, but the command itself will still be displayed. This might be a problem if you need to pass a password to the command.

In that case you can use the inputproperty to pass data directly to the input of the remote command without it being visible on the screen (or process list).

Refer to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069582/ant-input-password-for-sshexec) question for an example how to do this.